# Set modification date of files depending on their filename

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, finder

I have about 20 GB of videos just converted to HEVC, unfortunately they lost their metadata, so now it says every video was taken on the 16/12/2021.

I have all these videos marked as "Camera YYYY/MM/DD hhmmss.mov", is there a way with an Applescript or some kind of integration with Automator to change the modification date to the date indicated in the filename?

I've read about "touch -d" but I don't know how to integrate it into an Automator Workflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the target *files* are in the same *folder*, **and** only the target *files* are in that *folder*, then IMO the easier way to do this is to use **Terminal**.

First *change directory* to that *folder*, then copy and paste the following *compound command* in **Terminal** and press **enter**:

```
for f in *; do touch -t $(sed -E -e 's/[^0-9]//g' -e 's/([0-9]{12})([0-9]{2})/\1.\2/' <<< "$f") "$f"; done
```

**Notes:**

What the *compound command* is doing...

For each *file* the `touch` *command* will act on it getting the necessary *value* for the `-t` *option* by using *command substitution* `$(...)` and the `sed` *command*.

The `sed` *command* reduces `Camera YYYY/MM/DD hhmmss.mov` to `CCYYMMDDhhmm.SS`, e.g. `Camera 2021/12/16 202832.mov` becomes `202112162028.32` so the `touch` *command* executed is e.g.:

```
touch -t 202112162028.32 "Camera 2021/12/16 202832.mov"
```

The first `sed` *editing command*, `'s/[^0-9]//g'`, returns only the *digits* in the *filename*, e.g. `20211216202832`, while the second *editing command*, `'s/([0-9]{12})([0-9]{2})/\1.\2/'`, formats it so there is a `.` before the last two *digits* for the *seconds*, e.g. `202112162028.32`.

Thus `-t $(sed -E -e 's/[^0-9]//g' -e 's/([0-9]{12})([0-9]{2})/\1.\2/' <<< "Camera 2021/12/16 202832.mov")` becomes, e.g.: `-t 202112162028.32`