# Set modification date for files within sub-folders depending on start of filename

Tags: macos, terminal

This question is similar to:
[Set modification date of files depending on their filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70387062/set-modification-date-of-files-depending-on-their-filename)

However, I need to change the code so that it operates slightly different.

1. I want it to look at files in sub-folders as well.
2. I want the first 15 characters of the filename to be used as the modification date value; it will already be in the correct format for touch -m i.e., YYYYMMDDhhmm.ss

Can someone please help with the code for terminal? I tried modifying the code provided at the link above, but just couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
    for f; do
        if [[ ${f##.*/} =~ ^[0-9]{12}\.[0-9]{2} ]]; then
            echo touch -m -t $BASH_REMATCH -- "$f"
        fi
    done
' -- {} +
```

- `find` walks directory and calls `bash` with lists of paths of any files found

  - change `.` if not using the current directory
- `${f##*/}` extracts the basename
- `=~` does regular expression matching; on success, timestamp will be in `BASH_REMATCH` array

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.

I had to remove the "echo" for it to work, but otherwise works great!

Comment: goodo. it's common practice to "deactivate" potentially destructive commands so people are less likely to shoot themself in the foot if they run code that doesn't do what they want/expect

Comment: Are you able to assist with another similar problem? This time I'm trying to change date modified of folders (and subfolders) based on the most recent date modified of items within those folders. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77791258/change-date-modified-of-folder-based-on-most-recent-modified-file-within-folder